# C++ print packaged binary to stdout

Tags: c++, binary-data

I need to print packaged binary data to stdout in C++. Are there any STL libraries that can accomplish this? I know perl has this functionality but I need to be able to do it in only C++. If c++ does not have this functionality can someone please guide me on how I would go about programming something like this. Thank you.

Comment: I *think* he's asking how to open a binary file and write its contents to STDOUT.

Comment: There are a million and 1 command line tools that already do this (depending on your exact needs). What about octal dump 'od' on the command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the simplest way to write to stdout in binary mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888339/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-write-to-stdout-in-binary-mode)