# What is the simplest way to write to stdout in binary mode?

Tags: c, windows, binary, newline, stdout

I've been trying to figure out the best way to write binary data to stdout from a C program. It works fine on Linux, but I'm having issues when I compile on Windows because "\n" gets converted to "\r\n".

Is there a standard way to write to stdout in some sort of binary mode which avoids newline conversion? If not, what is the simplest way to get Windows to stop doing this?

I'm using GCC and MinGW, and writing to `stdout` using `fwrite`.

Comment: How are you currently outputting stuff?

Comment: have you tried using `fwrite` instead of `printf`?

Comment: I'm currently using fwrite.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `setmode(fileno(stdout), O_BINARY)`

Wrap it in an ifdef if you want to keep it compatible with Linux.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2017

Comment: `freopen(NULL, "wb", stdout)` can also be used, and is portable C. However, it may have unwanted truncation effects; see the Application Usage section of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html. For what it's worth, I think this text is wrong; when the new filename is NULL, there is no underlying `open` operation and thus the text about `O_TRUNC` does not apply.

Comment: @R.. you cant use `freopen` with a `NULL` filename in Windows, it will call the invalid parameter handler according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk2h68td.aspx and the default behavior of the invalid parameter handler is to crash the application.

Comment: @Vargas: `NULL` is not an invalid parameter to `freopen`, so I would say that's a bug in MSVCRT...

Comment: The link you posted states that is implementation-defined to allow streams to be reopened. My original point is that this is not a portable way to set the stream mode to binary.

Comment: or if "fileno" doesn't work -> raw values: stdin:0, stdout:1, stderr:2 due to MSDN documentation.

Comment: The documentation link no longer exists, here is the new link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx -- it's a documentation page for the `_setmode` function.

Comment: Out of personal experience let me add: Only run such programs on the windows command line, NOT in PowerShell as that one keeps mangling those characters

Comment: Can someone please rewrite this answer with an actual code snippet that's portable?

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like that (which is sort of cross platform):

```
FILE *const in = fdopen(dup(fileno(stdin)), "rb");
FILE *const out = fdopen(dup(fileno(stdout)), "wb");
/* ... */
fclose(in);
fclose(out);
```

Or you can use `write()` and `read()` system calls directly with `fileno(stdin)` and `fileno(stdout)`. Those system calls operate on lower level and don't do any conversions. But they also don't have buffering that you get from `FILE` streams.

Comment: The part about `write()` seems to be wrong, I still get newline conversions using it

Comment: Most likely you don't use system call `write()` that is `man -s 2 write`. There is no text/binary modes at that level.